# How to load value in input box on page load - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set or load a value in my input box as quickly when the page is loading. With my code below, i notice the input box is empty for about a second or 2 seconds before the value is filled in the input box. IS there a way i can make the input box load along with the value ?

**Loader.JS**

```
   const myKey = document.querySelectorAll('.key__input');
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        myKey.forEach(function (key) {
            key.value = "Hello Stack OverFlow";
            key.focus();
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be writing the event on [**Window: DOMContentLoaded event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) (DOM Ready) not on [<strike>Document: readystatechange event</strike>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event)

```js
 const keyInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.key__input');
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    keyInputs.forEach(function(keyInput) {
       keyInput.value = "Hello Stack OverFlow";
       keyInput.focus(); //focus will remain on the last selected element
     })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has
> been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
> images, and subframes to finish loading.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    const myKey = document.querySelectorAll('.key__input');
    myKey.forEach(function (key) {
        key.value = "Hello Stack OverFlow";
        key.focus();
    })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="key__input">
```